# How can I code my discord bot to add roles?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, discord, discord.py

I want my discord bot to give rolls to members in my server. This is what I'v tried but it doesn't work.

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

ROLE = '758778940977709056'

@client.command
async def addrole(ctx, member : discord.Member):
    role = get(member.guild.roles, name=ROLE)
    await member.add_roles(role)
    print(f'{member} was given {role}')
```

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail? In what way does it not work? What does it do instead of working? Are there any errors given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you added the role's `id` instead of the name. Id and name are different things. When using `utils.get` & the `name` kwarg, put the actual name of the role in (like `"Contributor"`).

```
role = get(member.guild.roles, name="name_of_your_role")
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any role called "ROLE" in your server ? If yes, you just have to add brackets. Otherwise, name it with the role you want to give to the user, but you still need to add brackets.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add it.
`ROLE = '758778940977709056`

Comment: Now you're telling that the name of the role is 758778940977709056
Change the role's ID to the role's name and it should work